# Good word for explicit?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

As in like "Explicit material" or "Explicit violence"

I'm thinking it's either 露骨 or 明白 but I'm unsure of if there's a difference in nuance between the two.

Comment: Do you mean in the context of warning to videos etc?

Comment: Yeah, sort of like "This film/video contains scenes of explicit violence."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that "explicit material" refers to sexually explicit materials, you usually should use 性的な表現 to avoid confusion. The word "explicit" in such a phrase is a kind of euphemism, and there is no good equivalent for this in Japanese. Recently, some have started to use 露骨な表現 to translate "explicit material", but this is still unsafe if your target readers are the general public. 露骨 by itself has had no connotation related to sex or violence in Japanese, and 露骨な表現 normally refers to direct insult, unreserved remarks, etc. If you want a broader phrase that includes graphic violence, drug-related contents and such, you can use 子供に不適切な内容, 成年向け表現, etc. 明白な内容/表現 ("clear content/expression") is out of the question.

"Explicit violence" is 露骨な暴力. Another common term used in the context of content rating is 残虐表現.

Answer (score -4):

Both 露骨 (rokotsu) and 明白 (meihaku) can be used to describe explicit or explicitness in Japanese. However, there is a slight difference in nuance between the two words.

露骨 (rokotsu) means "blatant" or "overt," and is used to describe something that is very clear or obvious. It is often used to describe things that are inappropriate or offensive in a very open or straightforward way.

明白 (meihaku) means "clear" or "obvious," and is used to describe something that is easy to understand or recognize. It is often used to describe things that are explicit or straightforward in a more neutral or objective way.

In the context of data, content, or material generally either 露骨 (rokotsu) or 明白 (meihaku) could be used, depending on the tone or perspective you wish to convey. 露骨 (rokotsu) might be more appropriate if you want to emphasize the offensiveness or inappropriateness of the content

明白 (meihaku) might be more appropriate if you want to simply describe the content as being explicit or straightforward, for example
彼の指示は明白だった。
He was explicit in his instruction.

Comment: But “explicit material” would *never* be used to mean “straightforward/clear material” in English, so your last paragraph makes no sense.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie I think you're criticism is misdirected. Here's an example:  彼の指示は明白だった。
He was explicit in his instruction.

Comment: But that's not the usage mentioned in the question.

Comment: sure, which is why I explained "露骨 (rokotsu) might be more appropriate if you want to emphasize the offensiveness or inappropriateness of the content." Is  it taboo to provide any extra info to help disambiguate the meaning of words as part of our answers here?? I get downvoted for being too informative?

Comment: The answer currently says 明白 can be used for the usage described in the question.

Comment: read the question. he's asking about both words: "I'm thinking it's either 露骨 or 明白 but I'm unsure of if there's a difference in nuance between the two."

Comment: Yes, and I read the answer as well, which says "In the context of "explicit material" or "explicit violence," either 露骨 (rokotsu) or 明白 (meihaku) could be used". It then goes on to explain 明白's usage which is not the context used in "explicit material" or "explicit violence". It contradicts itself.

Comment: would you believe a Japanese person? https://qr.ae/prYnjV

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142031/discussion-between-max-hodges-and-leebo).